# emulator cannot connect to internet via Proxyman blocked all my internet connections when Global Protect VPN with Okta authentication is on

Tags: ssl, proxy, android-emulator, vpn, okta

thank you for your help to answer my question.

I've been using Android Studio with it's Android Emulator for my workflow.
Currently, my company needs me to use Global Protect VPN with Okta Autenication in order to connect to development environment of the server.
However, when I use Proxyman on a new computer, I encountered an unknown problem.
Basically, I need to restart the emulator and override the certificate everytime my VPN connection ended (e.g. at lunch, I idle the computer for an hour therefore get into sleep mode).

Another weird senario is that my emulator still connects to the internet and works, meanwhile all other services e.g. Chrome browser could not connect to the internet.

I tired Proxyman's documentation to use Global Protect via openconnect.
(https://docs.proxyman.io/troubleshooting/proxyman-does-not-work-with-vpn-apps)

I got this error message:

> Failed to find or parse web form in login page

> Failed to complete authentication

My guess is it cannot trigger the Okta authenication browser.

Your help is highly appreciated as I got very frustrated by the current situtaion.

Thank you!